# Melhor valor para o parâmetro span/f na função lowess/loess no R

Tags: r

Eu estou enfrentando um problema com a suavização de curvas ajustadas pelas funções `lowess` ou `loess` no R, no que diz respeito a escolha do parâmetro de suavização `f` no `lowess` ou `span` no `loess`

Eu procurei algumas dicas na [web](https://www.biostars.org/p/128121/) e encontrei a resolução de um problema similar para a função `smooth.spline()` da seguinte maneira

```
tuneSpline = function(x,y,span.vals=seq(0.1,1,by=0.05),fold=10){
require(bootstrap)
fun.fit <- function(x,y,span) {smooth.spline(x = x,y = y,spar = span)}
fun.predict <- function(fit,x0) {predict(fit,x0)$y}

mae <- sapply(span.vals, function(span){
  y.cv <- bootstrap::crossval(
    x,y,fun.fit,fun.predict,span=span,ngroup = fold
    )$cv.fit
  fltr <- which(!is.na(y.cv))
  mean(abs(y[fltr]-y.cv[fltr]))
  })
span.vals[which.min(mae)] 

}


attach(cars)
tuneSpline(speed,dist,fold = length(dist))

# 0.75
```

tentei modificar esta rotina da seguinte maneira:

```
tuneSpline = function(x,y,span.vals=seq(0.1,1,by=0.05),fold=10){
  require(bootstrap)
  fun.fit <- function(x,y,f) {lowess(x = x,y = y, f= f)}
  fun.predict <- function(fit,x0) {predict(fit,x0)$y}

  mae <- sapply(span.vals, function(f){
    y.cv <- bootstrap::crossval(
      x, y, fun.fit, fun.predict, f=f, ngroup = fold
    )$cv.fit
    fltr <- which(!is.na(y.cv))
    mean(abs(y[fltr]-y.cv[fltr]))
  })
  span.vals[which.min(mae)]
}
```

No entanto quando rodo código no mesmo conjunto de dados, dá o seguinte erro:

```
attach(cars)
    tuneSpline(speed,dist,fold = length(dist))

# Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
# método não aplicável para 'predict' aplicado a um objeto de classe "list"
```

Agradeceria se pudessem ajudar, obrigado

Ps: não postei dados próprios pq não tenho ainda

obrigado desde já

Comment: O erro é causado porque `lowess` retorna uma lista de `x` e `y`, enquanto  `smooth.spline` retorna um objeto de classe `smooth.spline`. A função `crossvall` sabe o que fazer com o resultado da segunda, mas não da primeira. Tem certeza que esta solução serve para o seu problema? Talvez o ideal seja postar o seu problema original e não a sua tentativa de adaptar outra solução a ele.

Comment: Obrigado amigo pelo esclarecimento do erro. O meu problema é "simplesmente" encontrar uma maneira de optimizar as funções lowess ou loess para o melhor parâmetro de ajuste seja escolhido. O problema é q, infelizmente não tenho ideia  de como fazer isso, então buscando por problemas semelhantes encontrei essa soluçao para a função smooth.spline, então pensei em adaptá-lo para essas duas. O fato é que estava querendo utilizar um método de regressão(ajuste de curva) que não seja nem um pouco paramétrico (q não dependa de parâmetro algum, ou q sofra a mínima ação do usuário). Muito Obrg pela ajuda

Comment: Seu problema não parece ser muito complexo. Talvez a solução envolva colocar o `loess` dentro de uma função, e então utilizar `optimize` para o parâmetro em questão. Se você tem os dados de entrada, o parâmetro a ser otimizado (dentro de uma faixa) e o critério para considerar ótimo, encontrar o valor ideal não deve ser complicado.

Answer (score 1):

Seria bom vc postar qual o objetivo de fazer isso, pode ser que as funções loess não sejam a melhor solução. O objetivo desse tipo de função usualmente não é conseguir o maior ajuste aos dados mas representar melhor a tendência nos dados, eliminando tudo aquilo que for "ruido". É relativamente simples ajustar o parâmetro para minimizar alguma função de erro, mas talvez a melhor solução seja outro modelo.

Minimizando o erro quadrático:

```
tuneSpline = function(x,y,span.vals=seq(0.01,1,by=0.01)){
  theta <- function(x,y,f){ lowess(x=x,y=y, f= f)$y }
  mqe <- sapply(span.vals, function(f){
    ylow <- theta(x,y,f=f)
    fltr <- which(!is.na(ylow))
    mean((y[fltr]-ylow[fltr])^2)
  })
  list(mspan=span.vals[which.min(mqe)],mqe=cbind(span.vals,mqe))
}

attach(cars)
tuneSpline(speed,dist)$mspan
plot(tuneSpline(speed,dist)$mqe)

[1] 0.12
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]